# Regular Expression validate whitespaces in middle of a string

Tags: regex, string

I want to construct a regular expression which consists of alphanumeric characters and can have the whitespaces at the end of the string but not at the beginning or in the middle of string.

I came up with something like this `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$` and this does not allow space in the beginning but it does not work for the whitespace present in the middle of the string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide some example input and output.

Answer (score 4):

You're allowing spaces **OR** chars at the end, multiple times. Then you can have spaces followed by chars :

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$
```

[image]

Instead, change `[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*` part into `\s*` to ensure you won't have chars after spaces :

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*$
```

[image]

Comment: This was just the solution I needed! BTW: how did you make the visuals?

Answer (score 2):

If whitespace is only allowed at the end, then make that explicit:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*$
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use `<f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" />`

The spaces at the start and end will be automatically removed during form Validation and user will not be able to add spaces in the middle of the text.